# How to fix the message "Undefined variable..." in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, variables, error-handling

a problem suddenly occur on my website https://kcstravels.org I've this error message "***Notice: Undefined variable: gLWHJ9848 in /home/kcstra3473/public_html/wp-content/themes/sketch/404.php on line 1***" on the top and other places... Really I don't know what happened because everything worked well... So, I've tried to remove the "sketch" theme directory (and I precise that I don't know how this theme is present in theme directory and my default theme is **VisaHub**) but also K.O, I get always the same message.
How to fix that please... [The link of my website](https://kcstravels.org/)

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euArG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is not ERROR , this is just Notice messages, in general you can get various feedback about your scripts by PHP as mentions bellow :

- E_ERROR
- E_WARNING
- E_PARSE
- E_NOTICE
- E_CORE_ERROR
- E_CORE_WARNING
- E_COMPILE_ERROR
- E_COMPILE_WARNING
- E_USER_ERROR
- E_USER_WARNING
- E_USER_NOTICE
- E_STRICT
- E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR
- E_DEPRECATED
- E_USER_DEPRECATED
- E_ALL

this message is an E_NOTICE message that [says](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-reference/php-error-levels.php):

> A run-time notice indicating that the script encountered something that could possibly be an error, although the situation could also occur when running a script normally.

so the messages don't report very serious problems that need emergency action. anyway, This error means that within your code, there is a variable or constant which is not set. But you may be trying to use that variable. The error can be avoided by using the `isset()` function or by setting a default value for it (if you know what property makes the notices triggered exactly).
if you don't know, you can disable notice messages by PHP (keep that in mind: its better to disable error logs and same them in the log file when you are in production) :

for disableing all error messages :

```
error_reporting(0);
```

and for customizing them you can :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

with the above function, you will get all error levels except the notice ones.

if you are curious about what event can causes this problem Suddenly I can say that this may have a variety of reasons:

- changing PHP version by you or host providers
- adding new features or plugin
- changing error level by other scripts
- changing in host config and ...

Comment: You explain perfectly and I understand now. Thanks !

Comment: so you can select his answer as the best ! @YoussoufBalla

Comment: Great & perfect , tnx @behzadmsalehi